# Can I modify a terminal command to do additional stuff?

Tags: terminal, command-line

I've looked into aliases, functions... but I have not come up with anything satisfying. Let me give you a couple of scenarios:

- 95% of times that I `cd` into a folder, I follow up with a `ls`
  command.
- 90% of times that I `mkdir`, I then `cd` myself into it.

What would be the "cleanest" way to bind those commands together (or other functionality)?

Comment: Why didn't aliases work for you?

Comment: So should the cd result of mkdir then tack on the ls?

Comment: @bmike Well, a newly created directory will be empty, so ls prints nothing.

Comment: @Random832 you assume no flags on ls, but more importantly my question will reveal how broken / heavy handed a change is desired. I prefer aliases over functions, but both can attempt what is asked.

Comment: Coincidentally I was going to ask this same question. Will post my answer in some time.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Because an alias will not apply arguments to commands, only the last command receives the arguments. Try `alias foo='echo "cd "$1"" && echo "du "$@"" && echo "ls "$2""'`  then `foo fred barney dino`

Comment: @fd0 I am not doubting that aliases did not work.  I'm asking why.  There might be a simpler solution to the problem.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen aliases don't seem to accept arguments; They are just a string replacement tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put these lines in your `.zsrhc` or `.bashrc`

```
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
function cd {
builtin cd "$@" && ls -F
}
```

**Result ->**

[image]

Explanation from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20413/254607):

> Earlier in my .bashrc I have: [ -z "$PS1" ] && return, and everything
>   after that line only applies to interactive sessions, so this doesn't
>   affect how cd behaves in scripts.

Further info from [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20396/make-cd-automatically-ls#comment300011_20413):

> [ -z "$PS1" ] checks if the $PS (interactive prompt variable) is "zero length" (-z). If it is zero length, this means it has not been set, so Bash must not be running in interactive mode. The && return part exits from sourcing .bashrc at this point, under these conditions.

Btw, thanks for the question, it's really cool :)

**Edit :**

Another solution would be to integrate your ls to your prompt; I'm sure that you can do that with OhMyZsh ;)

Comment: In general don't use the same name as standard commands as cd ls rm etc as you will need to use these standard commands

Comment: @Mark I'm agree for 'rm -rf ~/*' ^^ But for a cd command, it's not really dangerous. And Carles want to 'upgrade existing commands', so...

Comment: I have to say that I've used this solution ever since @StrawHara published it and I've had 0 problems. I wanted to provide the "how it went" :) And it's really useful; this is how I use it (.zshrc): https://i.imgur.com/WHpROIE.png

Answer (score 13):

I'd tend to make a new command for this. I think it would even be logical to combine them into a single one.

```
go() {
    if [ -d "$1" ]; then
        cd "$1" && ls
    else
        mkdir -p "$1" && echo "Created directory $1" && cd "$1"
    fi
}
```

Comment: I like your idea combining these ones! :-)

Comment: This answer is also the cleanest as it doesn't disturb default definition of cd/mkdir when used by scripts

Comment: Sure, but what if you decide to start using the Go programming language? :P

Comment: @arxanas: You use makefiles? ;-)

Comment: hmmm I like this one. but if you accidentally mistype the name, you create a new directory. Is it hard to implement a check on a leave (cd `/.... ` or`../` or something) and delete the directory if it's empty? I mean if you leave a directory just check if it's empty and if so, delete it. if you don't want that, you can still use cd instead of go

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't solve the problem, it just creates a different one. In this case, I have to remember new commands. I want to *upgrade* **existing** commands. There must be something besides recompiling from the source, right? :\

Comment: What @Random832 did here is one of the cleanest and simplest way to build in one answer a composed command to your 2 examples. `&&` is the shell building glue to chain `command2` after `command1` if `command1` suceeded. This isn't any "recompiling from the source".

Answer (score 6):

I have tried adding things like these to my `.bashrc`:

```
cd() {
    command cd "$@"
    command ls
}

mkdir() {
    command mkdir "$@"
    command cd "$@"
}
```

However, I've found that this can mess up scripts that use the overridden commands, and the option handling can be fragile (for example, if you want to pass `-p` to the above `mkdir` command, it's also passed to `cd`). Better would be just to define aliases with different names (say, `c` or `mcd`).

Comment: inserting `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return` at the end of the file, before those functions, should help

Answer (score 5):

I think functions are the way to go. Something like

```
chglist() {
    cd "$1" && ls
}
```

as an example.